# regexp_like not accepting variable pattern

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a table

```
> create table employee(employeeid number(10), name varchar2(100),deptno
> 
>     number(10));
```

there are 1000 rows in this table.
when i am trying to create a procedure which will search a value and create a temporary table at run time & insert all results in that table.
In procedure: tableName is the name of temporary table which will be passed by application.
Search field is column name on which search will occur.
Searchvalue will be the pattern.

> ```
> create or replace PROCEDURE quick_search (tableName IN varchar2,searchfield IN 
> VARCHAR2,searchvalue IN varchar2) IS
> v_tableName varchar2(100);
> begin
> select count(tname) into v_tableName from tab where lower(tname) = tableName;
> if v_tableName = 1 then
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||tableName||'';
> case searchfield
>  when 'name' then
>                     execute immediate 'create table '||create_table||'  as
>                           Select Distinct employeeid FROM employee  where 
> regexp_like(NAME ,'||searchvalue||',''i'')';
>
>
> when 'deptno' then
>                    execute immediate 'create table '||create_table||'  as
>                           Select Distinct employeeid FROM employee  where 
> regexp_like(deptno ,'||searchvalue||',''i'')';
>
> end case;
> end if;
> if v_tableName =0 then
> case searchfield
>  when 'name' then
>                     execute immediate 'create table '||create_table||'  as
>                           Select Distinct employeeid FROM employee  where 
> regexp_like(NAME ,'||searchvalue||',''i'')';
>
>
> when 'deptno' then
>                    execute immediate 'create table '||create_table||'  as
>                           Select Distinct employeeid FROM employee  where 
> regexp_like(deptno ,'||searchvalue||',''i'')';
>
> end case;
> end if;
> end;
> ```

when i am executing this:

> `exec exec quick_search ('temp1','name','barbara') ;`

there is no object which exixt with name temp1 and barbara exist in my employee table.

I am getting error
Error report -
ORA-00904: "BARBARA": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.QUICK_SEARCH", line 53
ORA-06512: at line 1
00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the double quotes on the case-insensitive parameter but forgot to put it on the pattern parameter too. You'd have to modify each execute immediate of your procedure as follows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||create_table||' AS SELECT DISTINCT employeeid FROM employee WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, ''' || searchvalue || ''',''i'')';
```